# c# SnapObjects.Data retrieve data from model using the SqlSelect attribute

Tags: c#, sql

How can I retrieve data from my SQL-Model using the SqlSelect attribute??? For now i do this;

```cs
[SqlParameter(name: "first", dataType: typeof(int))]
[SqlParameter(name: "second", dataType: typeof(string))]
[SqlParameter(name: "third", dataType: typeof(DateTime))]
[FromTable("mytable", Schema = "DBA")]
[SqlSelect("mycustomselect", RawSelect = "someproperty, otherproperty")]
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    [SqlColumn("first")]
    public int First { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [SqlColumn("second")]
    public string Second { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [SqlColumn("third")]
    public DateTime Third { get; set; }
    ...
    [SqlColumn("someproperty")]
    public int Someproperty { get; set; }
    [SqlColumn("otherproperty")]
    public int Otherproperty { get; set; }
}
```

in my service I want to load this custom sqlSelect;

```cs
public async Task<MyClass> RetrieveOneAsync(int first, string second, DateTime third, string sqlselect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     Myclass myclass;

     var builder = ModelSqlBuilder.GetBuilder<Myclass>(_dataContext)
            .GetQueryBuilder(sqlselect);

     myclass = await _dataContext.SqlExecutor
          .SelectOneAsync<Myclass>(
          builder,
          new object[]
          {
              first,
              second,
              third
          },
          cancellationToken);

     return myclass;
}
```

i also tried it with a ParamValue;

```cs
public async Task<MyClass> RetrieveOneAsync(int first, string second, DateTime third, string sqlselect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     Myclass myclass;

     ParamValue firstParam = ParamValue.Input<int>("first", first);
     ParamValue secondParam = ParamValue.Input<string>("second", second);
     ParamValue thirdParam = ParamValue.Input<DateTime>("third", third);

     var builder = ModelSqlBuilder.GetBuilder<Myclass>(_dataContext)
            .GetQueryBuilder(sqlselect);

     myclass = await _dataContext.SqlExecutor
          .SelectOneAsync<Myclass>(
          builder,
          new object[]
          {
              firstParam,
              secondParam,
              thirdParam
          },
          cancellationToken);

     return myclass;
}
```

and my call;

```cs
var myclass = await RetrieveOneAsync(1, "test", DateTime.Now, "mycustomselect", default);
```

Everytime i didnt get the right row. I think there are some problems with my parameters. Maybe the DateTime value cause some problems.

I already read how to get the SQLSelect (this works):
[GetQueryBuilder](https://docs.appeon.com/snapobjects/3.0/api_reference/SnapObjects.Data/ModelSqlBuilder/Method/GetQueryBuilder.html)
[SqlSelectAttribute](https://docs.appeon.com/snapobjects/3.0/api_reference/SnapObjects.Data/ModelAttribute/Class/SqlSelectAttribute/SqlSelectAttribute.html)

but i dont get the right row from the table. Maybe i have to use a different function.
[SelectOneAsync](https://docs.appeon.com/snapobjects/3.0/api_reference/SnapObjects.Data/SqlExecutor/ISqlExecutor/Method/SelectOneAsync.html)

Answer (score 1):

ok i solved it. However i have to manually add the where clause instead of use the params.

```cs
public async Task<MyClass> RetrieveOneAsync(int first, string second, DateTime third, string sqlselect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     Myclass myclass;

     var builder = ModelSqlBuilder.GetBuilder<Myclass>(_dataContext)
            .GetQueryBuilder(sqlselect);

     builder
                .WhereValue("first", first)
                .AndWhereValue("second", second)
                .AndWhereValue("third", third);

     myclass = await _dataContext.SqlExecutor.SelectOneAsync<MyClass>(
                builder.ToSqlString(_dataContext));

     return myclass;
}
```